# ADB: When USB/Wifi debugging, can apps detect device identifiers?

Tags: android, adb, usb-debugging

When connecting to an android device (via USB or Wifi debugging) from a computer, is that computer's identifying (RSA key, MAC, anything) information visible to apps running?

That is, for example, if I enable USB debugging on an android, then connect to it from a computer by running adb, the android asks for permission to allow that computer's RSA key fingerprint. If an app is running on the android, I assume it can determine that a device is connected for USB debugging...but can the app determine any identifying info (in this case, the RSA key fingerprint) about the connected computer?

I'd like to be able to prevent apps from discovering any identifying info about the connected computer.

Have not tried anything yet.

Comment: To my knowledge apps the adb key identification is inaccessible by apps.Android does not provide an API to get access to such information available only in adbd. May be system apps can do or may be only system apps of certain device manufacturer. As each manufacturer can modify Android it may be theoretically possible for some vendors...